# Mysql group by with multiple columns with inner joins

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have 3 tables, `products`, `productscategories` and `categories`.

The `productscategories` is a many to many table with only id numbers of the other two tables.

**The result without the group by looks like this:**

```
id | Url                   | Category
-------------------------------------
1 | http://example.com/12 | hat
2 | http://example.com/12 | shoe
3 | http://example.com/13 | hat
4 | http://example.com/13 | jacket
5 | http://example.com/14 | hat
6 | http://example.com/14 | socks
```

Now I want to exclude every row with the same `url` if it contains any of the choosen categories, in this case `jacket` and `shoe`.

**The unwanted result looks like this:**

```
id | Url                   | Category
-------------------------------------
1 | http://example.com/12 | hat
3 | http://example.com/13 | hat
5 | http://example.com/14 | hat
```

Because `url` with id 13 includes `jacket` I don't want it there. Same goes for `url` with 14 which includes `shoe`.

This accur because I have multiple categories and multiple urls that are not aware of each other.

**The sql for the above:**

```
SELECT * FROM products
JOIN productscategories ON products.id = productscategories.product_id
JOIN categories ON categories.id = productscategories.category_id
WHERE categories.slug NOT IN (
  'shoe',
  'jacket',
) 
GROUP BY products.image_url
```

**The wanted result:**

```
id | Url                   | Category
-------------------------------------
5 | http://example.com/14 | hat
```

How can I make an sql query that makes url aware of the category, like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM products
  JOIN productscategories ON products.id = productscategories.product_id
  JOIN categories ON categories.id = productscategories.category_id
 GROUP BY products.image_url
HAVING sum( categories.slug IN('shoe','jacket') )=0
```

`categories.slug IN('shoe','jacket')` - return 1 if category in set or 0 if not. `sum()` - return count of shoe/jacket in group. `HAVING` filter group with shoe/jacket in it.

Comment: That was a strange looking answer, but it works in my tests and it's lightning fast as well (30-60 times faster than other answers). No pitfalls? Thanks!

Comment: @JensTörnell on MySQL this works fine. On other RDBMS may be need `sum( case when categories.slug IN('shoe','jacket') then 1 else 0 end )`

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion 1: `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT * FROM products
JOIN productscategories ON products.id = productscategories.product_id
JOIN categories ON categories.id = productscategories.category_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT 1
      FROM products p2
      JOIN productscategories pc2 ON p2.id = pc2.product_id
      JOIN categories c2 ON c2.id = pc2.category_id
      WHERE c2.slug IN ('shoe','jacket')
      AND p2.url = products.url 
  )
```

Suggestion 2: `OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM products
JOIN productscategories ON products.id = productscategories.product_id
JOIN categories ON categories.id = productscategories.category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN products p2 ON products.url = p2.url
LEFT OUTER JOIN productscategories pc3 ON p2.id = pc2.product_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories c2 ON c2.id = pc2.category_id AND c2.slug IN ('shoe','jacket')
WHERE c2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: I just tried them both and they worked but the loading time goes from 1 second to like a half minute. :(  You have a `pc3` in your code. It should be `pc2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM products
JOIN productscategories ON products.id = productscategories.product_id
JOIN categories ON categories.id = productscategories.category_id
) AS A
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT Url FROM products
JOIN productscategories ON products.id = productscategories.product_id
JOIN categories ON categories.id = productscategories.category_id
WHERE Categories.slug IN ('jacket', 'shoe')
GROUP BY url
) B ON B.url = A.url
WHERE B.url IS NULL
```